# Bootstrap divs don't stack

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using bootstrap to achieve a grid type layout.

However when the XS class is applied (mobile devices) my two divs don't stack.

My first div is setup like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right" id="ad-container">
Content
</div>
```

And my second one like this:

```
<main id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 content-area" role="main">
Content
</main>
```

When i view it in mobile size, the `<main>` element simply sits directly ontop of the 'ad container'.

Could the `pull-right` be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pull-right` seems to be the problem. To ensure that your content area comes on the left on bigger screens but is stacked below the ad container on mobiles use [Column Ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-9" id="ad-container">
  Content
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-pull-3 content-area" role="main">
  Content
  </div>
</div>
```

`col-md-push-9` "pushes" the column to the right by 9 and `col-md-pull-3` "pulls" the column to the left by 3 on "md" or greater screens.

Comment: Fixed it brilliantly! Thanks